# Wifi main router + wifi extender conflict

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

When I am trying to connect to the main router, the IP address that the router is giving me by DHCP is wrong (for ex my home network is 192.168.1. and the router is giving me 169.116.). I have a connected tplink extender to the main router and the extender is giving me the correct IP address ranges. What should I do to obtain the correct IP address from the main router? Sorry I am not very related to networking, so can somebody provide me with the steps.

Comment: Configure the extender to provide address in the same subnet as the router.

Comment: The main router is giving me wrong addresses not the extender

Comment: So change the subnet of the router?  Both subnets are actually valid.

Comment: Consider giving the extender a static IP on main routers network outside DHCP pool.  Make sure the extender doesn't have a DHCP server or that it's off, you don't want two DHCP servers providing answer to IP requests. If the extender is really a router, make sure it's is access point mode, or not routing, all you really want to have enabled is wifi on the extender, and like I started out, I always have better luck keeping this stable by just giving the extender a static IP... Normally I would not suggest static ip assignment, but IMO 2nd network devices on a home network are the exception.

Comment: Why is your router configured to give out IP addresses owned by JPMorgan Chase & Co? (169.116.*.*)

Comment: haha no I think it is a self-assigned IP address. My devices are not getting IP from the main router. I turned off the DHCP server on the extender and gave it a static IP not in the range of the DHCP. I don't know what is the problem. What I am doing is giving my devices static IP and it is working but DHCP server is not giving IPs